# sqlite issues on iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

i can execute query but i can see the only last value  of **list_ID**

i want to access 4 but i am getting 6  ???

```
list_ID is ----------------------->is 4
2010-12-24 12:57:07.507 DatabaseTest[3398:207]  QUERY EXECUTION
2010-12-24 12:57:07.508 DatabaseTest[3398:207] bxbxbxmnb
2010-12-24 12:57:07.508 DatabaseTest[3398:207]  list_ID is ----------------------->is 5
2010-12-24 12:57:07.509 DatabaseTest[3398:207]  QUERY EXECUTION
2010-12-24 12:57:07.510 DatabaseTest[3398:207] bxbxbxmnb
2010-12-24 12:57:07.511 DatabaseTest[3398:207]  list_ID is ----------------------->is 6
```

this is the code

```
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)

            {


                acat=[[[Cat_tableList alloc]init]autorelease];



                /////////////  statement////////

            NSLog(@" QUERY EXECUTION");




                                //  sStudent.cat_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                acat.list_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                acat.cat_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                acat.names=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                acat.content=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];








                [appDelegate.catLists addObject:acat];
(@"final AUTo_ID array is  ............%@",acat.content);
                NSLog(@" list_ID is ----------------------->is %@",acat.list_id);  i just want value to b 4 so that i can use this somewhere
                ///////////////


            }
```

Comment: @prajakta--list_ID 4 means....you want to access 4th row of table out of 6?...be more clear

Comment: yes exactly ...kindly suggest  whenever i access list_id from other class i get 6 but i want 4

Comment: you want to access the value at row 4, and in your table 6 value are use save all value in array and create one more array and do for loop for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ [newarray addobjectatindex:i];}

Comment: i tried but no luck :(  can you  show me what you meant

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show your sqlite query statement but  ok....

here You are using 4 objects of Cat_tableList class whose values (pointer values) changes for each value of your loop runs for each row of database table.....so this problem occurs because last record might be of list_ID = 6..

I suggest

1. Use an `array of array` or `array of dictionaries` to store all these and then you can use any one of them...
2. Also you can `modify your sqlite request` (I am not sure what you used here i think you used SELECT * FROM Table1)....modify it and change to `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE list_ID=4`;
   (list_ID should be replaced with exact name of column in your database table)..

**Edit**

If you want exact that id =4 you can use something like this

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)

            {

if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)] isEqualToString:@"4"])
{
                acat=[[[Cat_tableList alloc]init]autorelease];


                acat.list_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                acat.cat_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                acat.names=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                acat.content=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];





                [appDelegate.catLists addObject:acat];
(@"final AUTo_ID array is  ............%@",acat.content);
                NSLog(@" list_ID is ----------------------->is %@",acat.list_id);
}



   }
```

**Edit---2**

Consider following example if you want all your values of table

```
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
                    {

                NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];



NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                    [arr addObject:str1];
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                    [arr addObject:str2];
NSString *str3 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                    [arr addObject:str3];

                [appDelegate.catLists addObject:arr];
                [arr release];
            }
```

Now  catLists has all values of database

Now access it by

```
[[appDelegate.catLists objectAtIndex:int1]objectAtIndex:int2];
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: thats what i am saying value of list_id is= 6 (which i am getting)not 4 so i cant execute query  based on table selection ..  this is my NSMutable araay  [appDelegate.catLists addObject:acat];
  how to do array of array???

Comment: thanks but what about 5, 6 ... see i want to display values based on 4,5,6 so i need all of them .. since i am getting only 6 so i cant display data of 4 and 5 based on user row select :(

Comment: thanks saawan , i did some other way can you plz check my code and let me know thanks again

Answer (score 0):

first i did this to get the current index of any row clicked

```
appDelegate.a1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];// a1 is new array 


            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)

            {
         acat.list_id=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

                NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:acat.list_id,nil];




                [appDelegate.a1 addObjectsFromArray:myArray2];





                [appDelegate.a1 addObject:myArray2];



}
```

then to get the list_id value in other class i am doing this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic -- create and push a new view controller


{
rowID=[[appDelegate.a1 objectAtIndex:0]intValue] +[indexPath row];
[self calldatabase];
}



void(calldatabase)
{
 NSString *query=  [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from list_tbl where cat_id=%@ and list_id=%d",aCat.cat_id, rowID ];// here rowid starts from 4 and keep inc by 1

}
}
```

/// this is working but i want to know is this good way and wont consume much memory??? plz suggest
Thanks

Comment: There are lots of probems with your code..................... NSArray  * myArray2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:acat.list_id,nil];//array for a single value?...............and now adding same value two times? i mean the string and the array both?
[appDelegate.a1 addObjectsFromArray:myArray2];
[appDelegate.a1 addObject:myArray2];

Comment: ok lets say i follow your way but how will i get value in next class can you help me  what should i pass in my NSString *query???

Comment: what will the value of list_id to be passed inside NSString *query??

Comment: thats the right way to pass object to another class,you are passing the object to your appdelegate class,as object of an array and accessing that array in other classes as well.Thats good as your appdelegate class is singelton class.There is no issue with this.

Comment: make your question more clear i think make confused other with your question

Answer (score 0):

Do Code in this way

Call sqlite and  store all data in appdelegate array then use as you want to use

you just have to pick data with condition if you want to pick data from 4 ,5 6 out of array then use this code

newarray = [[nsmutablearray alloc]init];
for(int = 3 ; i<[appdelegatearray count];i++)
{
   [newarray addobject:[appdelegatearray objectatindex:i];
}

in this way you can do any thing hope its help to you else tell you question more clearly i think you are afraid to share

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to everyone who helped me as now my problem is fixed

This is how I did this

```
rowID=[[appDelegate.a1 objectAtIndex:rowPointer]intValue];, where rowPointer=[indexPath row];
```

first I am storing all the values in array and then I am accessing them via index :-)